# symbols from static cc_library dependency in so missing

Tags: bazel

How can i tell bazel to link a precompiled (static) library?

I have referenced an existing static library project (xy.BUILD):

```
cc_library(
  name="xy",
  srcs=["lib/x86_64/libxy.a"],
    hdrs=["include/xy.h"],
  includes=["include"],
  #linkstatic=True,                          <---- *1
  #alwayslink=True,
  visibility=["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Inside another project (BUILD):

```
cc_library(
  name="myxylib",
  hdrs=["myxylib.h"],
  srcs=["myxylib.c"], 
  visibility=["//visibility:public"],
  deps=["@xy//:xy"],
  linkopts = ["-pthread", 
            #"-Lexternal/xy/lib/x86_64/",    <---- *2
            #"-lxy", 
            #"-z defs"
  ],
```

)

... as an external dependency (new_local_repository in WORKSPACE). I can use the header files and compile the code as an .so library but the symbols from the static library are missing inside the shared object, because bazel does not set the -L and -l flags (see comments *2) automatically for the dependency. Is there any way to forca bazel to do this automatically? I already tried the parameters at comment *1 but that doesnt help.

I feel very uncomfortable with setting the -L and -l flags manually because i will have to support different architectures and i whould prefer to set the paths for the architecture dependent different libraries only ones instead of repeating it in every inherited artifact.

Comment: Are you getting an error linking or are you trying to distribute a self-contained library?

Comment: I dont get any errors during the build, but I want the symbols from the static library (xy) to be included inside myxylib. This works if i add "-Lexternal/xy/x86_64 -lxy" to the linkopts, but as the paths are platform dependent i whould prefer to have some bazel flag or similar to make bazel append this automatically based on the dependency information it alrady has. The location of the libxy.a file is already given inside the srcs parameter of cc_library(xy) so imho i should not have to repeat myself inside the definition for cc_library(myxylib)

Answer (score 4):

Using cc_binary instead of cc_library with modified linkopts (-shared) and name("**lib** myxylib **.so**"):

```
cc_binary(
  name="libmyxy.so",
  hdrs=["myxylib.h"],
  srcs=["myxylib.c"], 
  visibility=["//visibility:public"],
  deps=["@xy//:xy"],
  linkopts = ["-shared"],
)
```

... seems to be usefull as an workaround as long as one is happy with getting everything linked into the binary without specific control. This also includes a clib version binding.

Comment: There are no 'hdrs' attribute in 'cc_binary' rule.

Answer (score 3):

`cc_library` doesn't link in its dependencies until it's combined into a `cc_binary` (everything will be linked into the `cc_binary` without you having to specify it).

There isn't an elegant way to force it to link everything into a `cc_library`.  You could use a `genrule` with [$location](http://bazel.io/docs/build-encyclopedia.html#location) so you don't need to specify a specific architecture. Or feel free to [file an feature request](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues) if this is something you'd like to see us add.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did file a feature request (https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/492). In the meantime I will try it with genrule and $location

Answer (score 1):

Like Jan mentions, you can use cc_binary() to create a library. You should use the linkshared=1 attribute so Bazel issues the right flags for generating a DSO.