# build a complete static library with some deps using bazel?

Tags: c++, bazel

trying to build a static library offering to someone else, and the BUILD file like:

```
cc_library(
 name = "liba",
 srcs = ["src/*.cpp", "src/*.h"],
 deps = [
   "//path:lib_b",
   "//path:lib_c",
 ]
)
```

then I find the *liba* does not contains .o object files from *lib_b* & *lib_c*, and its not a independent library, so how could I build a liba contains all the contents from *lib_b* & *lib_c*?

I am using an old version bazel(0.14.1), and found a related question([symbols from static cc_library dependency in so missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845940/symbols-from-static-cc-library-dependency-in-so-missing?newreg=0a4bf5c53686420faa24d4b720b5e6cc)), but the *cc_binary* mentioned in the comments only generated an binary.

Comment: A static library is really nothing more than an archive of object files. Linking with it is like linking with the individual object files themselves. A static library is not linked like a shared library (or an executable program), and doesn't have references to its own dependencies. If you want to link with a static library, you need to link with all its dependencies as well.

Comment: the deps of *liba* contain hundreds .o files,  so it could be very annoying for me to find & link all of them manually, I am wondering bazel may could finish this job for me if I configure someting right?

Comment: I hope you mean that `liba` *contains* "hundreds .o files", not depend on them. Anyway, when you link your actual application (for the actual executable program) you must link with both `liba` as well as `libb` and `libc` (in the correct order as well). Doesn't Bazel set up this for you?

Comment: `cc_library` and any other `*_library` rule should NOT be used as the result artifact used outside the bazel. Play with cc_binary, maybe `linkstatic` option will be helpful https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary.